# Чтение текстовой задачи, её решение и добавление ответа в файл (python)

Tags: python

```py
import docx
document = docx.Document("zadanie.docx")
all_paragraphs = document.paragraphs
numbers=[]
for paragraph in all_paragraphs:
    text = (paragraph.text)
    list_of_text=text.split()
    for word in list_of_text:
        if word.isdigit():
            numbers.append(int(word))
result = numbers[1]-numbers[2]+numbers[3]

answer = "Ответ: " + str(result)
document.add_paragraph(answer)
document.save("task.docx")
```

> result = numbers[1]-numbers[2]+numbers[3]
> IndexError: list index out of range

Выдает ошибку. Что делать не подскажете?

**Задачка 25.

На складе 35 пакетов муки

Грузчик взял 15

Потом вернул 2 брака

Сколько пакетов муки на складе?**

также записано в ворде. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Можете изменять задачку, главное чтобы оставалась суть

Answer (score 1):

Вообще ошибка означает, что вы обращаетесь к list'у по индексу, которого не существует

Во-первых проверить, что содержит list. Я его сразу создам

```py
test_list = [35, 15, 2]
print(test_list)

#out
#[35, 15, 2]
```

Соответственно, нумерация по индексу начинается с нуля

```py
print(test_list.index(35)) # справшиваем индекс по значению 35

#Out
#0
```

Следовательно, в данном листе можно обратиться только к индексам 0,1,2.

А если я обращусь вот так

```py
print(test_list[3])
```

я получу вашу ошибку

> IndexError: list index out of range

А вот так все сработает

```py
result = test_list[0] - test_list[1] + test_list[2]

#Out result
# 22
```

Comment: спасибо! помогло

Comment: На здоровье! обратите внимание вот сюда: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), поскольку тут не принято говорить "спасибо" в комментариях, но вы можете оценить ответ и/или отметить его как принятый